# Pop up message box in PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to create a pop up window inside the game which will display result for a small game, if you click OK, the game continues, but that doesn't matter. How do you even create such box so it will pop up when I call it? I read question with `pgu`, what is `pgu`? Is it another external library?

Comment: you can treat popup window as another sprite in Pygame. Create class with `draw()`, `update()`, `handle_event()` and use similar like `Player` or `Enemy`.

Comment: [PyGame GUIs](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui) - there is link to `pgu` and `OcempGUI`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can treat popup window like another sprite in Pygame.

Create class with `draw()`, `update()`, `handle_event()` and use it similar to  `Player` and `Enemy`.

Simple example with own [Button in PyGame](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover)

---

You may also use one of PyGame modules for GUI but some of themy may need changes in code because they run own event loop.

Example GUIs

- [PGU](https://www.pygame.org/project/108)
- [OcempGUI](https://www.pygame.org/project/125)

More on PyGame page: [PyGame GUIs](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/gui)

Answer (score 8):

I used `tkinter` and created a message box,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
Tk().wm_withdraw() #to hide the main window
messagebox.showinfo('Continue','OK')
```

Comment: wow dude, thanks! I wanted to use the messagebox but tkinter window showed up.

Comment: `messagebox.showinfo(title='Info', message='Hello World')`, first argument is the window title, second argument is the message

Comment: But ... we are talking about a **window in Pygame**. We all know (I guess) about Tkinter widgets ...

Comment: the question is in context of pygame

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyZenity](http://brianramos.com/?page_id=38), installable via Pip. Then, you can just do:

```
from PyZenity import *
cancel = Question('Continue game?')
```

Comment: How do you install it on ubuntu?

Comment: I'm on my Windows machine right now, but it should be something like `pip install pyzenity` or `pip install PyZenity` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pyautogui alert or confirm.

```py
    if something_happens:
       pyautogui.alert("you have done this")
```