# How can I control collision from sprites?

Tags: python, pygame

There is a question in stackoverflow with the title:
Make a line as a sprite with its own collision.
Rabbid 76 answered this question with an example

My Question:

How must the example be changed so that when the line hits the image, a "hit" message appears, which disappears again after 1 seconds.

Then a second message comes up for 1 seconds when the line leaves the picture.

Comment: See [Pygame "pop up" text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70996802/pygame-pop-up-text/70996856#70996856)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)/[`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group).

Create a text sprite when an obstacle is hit. Add the time at which the text must disappear again as an attribute to the sprite.
In addition, the obstacle must be prevented from generating continuous "hit" texts in successive frames. When an obstacle is hit, it is marked by setting a Boolean attribute in the obstacle. As long as this attribute is set, the obstacle cannot generate a new "hit" text. When the objects no longer collide, the attribute is reset:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        rel_hit_pos = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, obstacle)
        if rel_hit_pos:
            if obstacle.hit == False:
                obstacle.hit = True
                hit_sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                hit_sprite.image = hit_text_image
                hit_pos = ball.rect.x + rel_hit_pos[0], ball.rect.y + rel_hit_pos[1]
                hit_sprite.rect = hit_sprite.image.get_rect(center = hit_pos)
                hit_sprite.end_time = current_time + pop_up_seconds * 1000
                text_sprites.add(hit_sprite)
        else:
            obstacle.hit = False
```

[`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) the sprite when the current time is greater than the end time of the sprite:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for hit_sprite in text_sprites:
        if current_time > hit_sprite.end_time:
            hit_sprite.kill()
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_popup_text_2/build/web/)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 40)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bounds = pygame.Rect(20, 20, 360, 360)
hit_text_image = font.render("hit", True, "yellow")
text_pos_and_time = []
pop_up_seconds = 1

ball = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
ball.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.draw.circle(ball.image, "red", (20, 20), 20)
ball.rect = ball.image.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center)
ball.pos = pygame.Vector2(ball.rect.center)
ball.dir = pygame.Vector2(random.uniform(0.5, 1), random.uniform(0.5, 1))
ball.dir.normalize_ip()
ball.speed = 0

obstacles = []
for pos in [(100, 200), (300, 100), (250, 300)]:
    obstacle = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
    obstacle.image = pygame.Surface((60, 60))
    obstacle.image.fill("darkgreen")
    obstacle.rect = obstacle.image.get_rect(center = pos)
    obstacle.hit = False
    obstacles.append(obstacle)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([ball, *obstacles])
text_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

text = font.render("+1", True, (0, 255, 0))
text_pos_and_time = []
pop_up_seconds = 1

player = pygame.Rect(0, 80, 40, 40)
coins = [pygame.Rect(i*100+100, 80, 40, 40) for i in range(3)]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            ball.dir = pygame.Vector2(random.uniform(0.5, 1), random.uniform(0.5, 1))
            ball.dir.normalize_ip()
            ball.speed = 5

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.x = (player.x + (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * 3) % 300    

    ball.pos += ball.dir * ball.speed
    ball.rect.center = round(ball.pos.x), round(ball.pos.y)
    if not bounds.contains(ball.rect.inflate(2, 2)):
        if ball.rect.left <= bounds.left or ball.rect.right >= bounds.right:
            ball.dir.x *= -1
        if ball.rect.top <= bounds.top or ball.rect.bottom >= bounds.bottom:
            ball.dir.y *= -1
        ball.rect.clamp_ip(bounds)
        ball.pos = pygame.Vector2(ball.rect.center)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    for obstacle in obstacles:
        rel_hit_pos = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, obstacle)
        if rel_hit_pos:
            if obstacle.hit == False:
                obstacle.hit = True
                hit_sprite = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
                hit_sprite.image = hit_text_image
                hit_pos = ball.rect.x + rel_hit_pos[0], ball.rect.y + rel_hit_pos[1]
                hit_sprite.rect = hit_sprite.image.get_rect(center = hit_pos)
                hit_sprite.end_time = current_time + pop_up_seconds * 1000
                text_sprites.add(hit_sprite)
        else:
            obstacle.hit = False

    for hit_sprite in text_sprites:
        if current_time > hit_sprite.end_time:
            hit_sprite.kill()

    window.fill(0)    
    pygame.draw.rect(window, "gray", bounds, 3)
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    text_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```